# Use live server database but on local server code

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I have an asp.net application on a dedicated server. I want to use my live application database which is on live SQL Server with my local code for some testing purposes.

The solution that I already used: use live server connection string but it does not work - I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Comment: I think your connection string is wrong. Simply create an UDL file then run it and fill server name, logon information and select database. Click on test connection. If everything is OK you can open UDL file with notepad and copy connection string.

Comment: Check if the connection string is correct. If the connection string is correct then issue is with the server accessibility. Server might not exposing port 1433 to the public traffic. 1433 port is used for SQL server connections. You need to open the port for Inbound connection using Windows Firewall Settings on the server.